# use regex with oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm relatively new to the regex with oracle and I was wondering how to split a text beetween two pipe.
Here is the input string : 1||01|SOME_TEXT||02|OTHER_TEXT||

What I want is to retrieve **01|SOME_TEXT** and **02|OTHER_TEXT**

Here is what I tried :

```
`Select regexp_substr('1||01|SOME_TEXT||02|OTHER_TEXT||', '[^\|\|]', 1, Level) From Dual
Connect By regexp_substr('1||01|SOME_TEXT||02|OTHER_TEXT||', '[^\|\|]', 1, Level) Is Not Null`
```

I don't know how to filter only strings that are between double pipe AND maybe containing some single pipe.

Any help are welcome.

**UPDATE**

I have made it with the following pattern : (\w)+\|(\w)+(\|){2,2}+?

Comment: HINT: if you want to match a specif string/character a specific number of times, you can pass `{n,n}` where n is any number, like `[A]{3,3}` will match `AAA`

Comment: I have tried your solution. [a-zA-Z0-9_\|]+(\|){2,2}+?
But I would like it to be non greedy but I don't know how to do it

Comment: It might look like a cheating, but try replacing double pipes with some other character and then use it as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
Select regexp_substr('1||01|SOME_TEXT||02|OTHER_TEXT||', '[^|]+\|[^|]+', 1, Level) From Dual
Connect By regexp_substr('1||01|SOME_TEXT||02|OTHER_TEXT||', '[^|]+\|[^|]+', 1, Level) Is Not Null
```

I've kept your original query but slightly changed the pattern.

My pattern `[^|]+\|[^|]+` contains three parts:

- `[^|]+` - a string without pipes
- `\|` - a single pipe
- `[^|]+` - another string without pipes

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `(?<=\|{2}).+?(?=\|{2})`.

Details: it uses lookbehind `(?<=\|{2})` and lookahead `(?=\|{2})` to capture everything between double pipe `\|{2}`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iD3vEg/1)

Comment: I don't know why but it does not work with Oracle. I have made it with the following pattern : (\w)+\|(\w)+(\|){2,2}+? but don't hesitate if you have a better solution. Thanks

Comment: Oracle only supports basic grouping () and backreferences. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm#r12c1-t7